# Paginate API response without database (count) with Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mailchimp, laravel-5.8

I am using: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-newsletter

Controller

```
if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')){
  $members = Newsletter::getMembers('subscribers');
  return view('admin.newsletter', ['members' => $members]);
} else {
  return redirect('admin');
}
```

View

```
@foreach ($members['members'] as $member)
  <tr>
   <td>{{ $member['unique_email_id'] }}</td>
   <td>{{ $member['email_address'] }}</td>
   <td>{{ $member['timestamp_opt'] }}</td>
   <td>{{ $member['last_changed'] }}</td>
   <td>
     <a href="{{ url('/newsletter/status') }}
     {{ '/' . $member['email_address'] }}">
     {{ ucfirst($member['status']) }}</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Can anyone walk me through paginating the data response without the regular something->paginate(10);

I was unable to find concrete answers on Stackoverflow or Google.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The source code of the `getMembers()` function is this:

```
public function getMembers(string $listName = '', array $parameters = [])
{
    $list = $this->lists->findByName($listName);
    return $this->mailChimp->get("lists/{$list->getId()}/members", $parameters);
}
```

The **Mailchimp** API documentation list the *optional parameters* [here](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#read-get_lists_list_id_members).

Two parameters are intersting for pagination: `count` and `offset`.

For what I read above you can try something like this:

```
$members = Newsletter::getMembers('subscribers', ['count'=>10, 'offset'=>0]);
```

Change the `offset` based on your *current page* and the `count` on your desired results.

Comment: @Cameron do you have any feedback on this answer?

Comment: Yeah, seems interesting, I'll need to do additional research about how to go about this.

Comment: I ended up just storing the information into my database as a cronjob and paginating it that way.